# Angular HttpParams to object, Object.defineProperty creates property but is out of scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to transform HttpParams into an object by dynamically creating the properties on the object based off what is in HttpParams.

```
private transformParamsToObject(params: HttpParams) {
    let newObject = {};
    params.keys().forEach(x => Object.defineProperty(newObject, x, { value: params.get(x) }));
    const foo = Object.assign({}, newObject);
    return foo;
}
```

From what I can see in the debugger, it's defining the properties, but they don't seem to be in scope when I assign that object to foo. Even if I just return newObject, it doesnt have the properties defined on them in scope.

I feel like I may be missing something very simple here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They are not enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), that's why `Object.assign` doesn't find them. But there's no reason to use `Object.defineProperty` here when you can just assign the property directly, and there's no reason to use `Object.assign` to create yet another `foo` object next to `newObject`. Just do

```
private transformParamsToObject(params: HttpParams) {
    let newObject = {};
    for (const x of params.keys())
        newObject[x] = params.get(x);
    return newObject;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! So much easier. I was only re-assigning to prove the point that they werent being set. 

Thanks so much

Comment: They were set, they just weren't visible.